# Cancel button for database Query/progress bar in Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I don't have a minimal, reproducible example because I am not sure if this is even possible.

Is there a cancel button option that can be set to stop all functions running that are related to the progress bar when using the progress bar in a shiny app?

I have looked online but can not seem to find anything that answers my question. I hope this isn't to vague of a question and I hope someone can help me find the solution I am looking for. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to check `AsyncProgress` from library([ipc](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fellstat/ipc/blob/master/inst/doc/shinymp.html)).

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at this but it isn't exactly what I am looking for. However I think that is my fault with my wording. What I want is not to stop all other functions while the progress bar is running, I want to have a button, that when clicked, cancels the progress bar and what it is loading.